# How to solve complex equation $\cos z = 4$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

So, I know that $\cos z =4 \Rightarrow z = \arccos(4) = i\ln(\arccos 4 + \sqrt{\arccos^24  -1}) = i(\ln(\sqrt{\arccos^2 4}+ \arccos^2 4 -1) + i(\arg(\arccos 4 + \sqrt{\arccos^2 4 -1}) + 2k\pi), \ \ k \in  \Bbb Z$

But I don't know what to do next and how to find modulus and arg.

Comment: Why don't you try by writing $cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$ and make a change of variable $w=e^{iz}$?

Comment: @CarlIO Just wanted to ask, whether we multiply the expression $e^{iz} + e^{-iz} = 8$ by $e^{iz}$ simply to make the expression simpler or is there other reasons? Also, would id make sense to multiply everything by $e^{-iz}$?

Comment: $w=e^{iz}$ or $t=e^{-iz}$ shouldn't make any difference. 
Of course, you have to multiply by $w$ or $t$. But, not just to make the expression look simpler. Notice that you would obtain a 2nd order polynomial equation.

Comment: @CarlIO Thank you for clarification!

Comment: Did you obtain something useful?

Comment: @CarlIO Yes? I am not sure, whether I understood your question.

Comment: I wondered if you finally solved it and if my help was useful

Comment: @CarlIO Yes, you were helpful and I solved it long time ago.